# Problem with testing logout function in Django project

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

When I test this function response status is 403.

```
def test_logout(self):
    request = self.factory.post('http/api/logout/')
    request.user = self.user1
    response = logout(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My Authentification view:

```
def login(request):
serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
user = serializer.validated_data['user']
token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
return Response({'token': token.key})

def logout(request):
request.auth.delete()
return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

How can I test the logout function view?

Comment: You forgot authenticate your user https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

Comment: no, i did it in a setUp function:

Comment: def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(
            username='test_user',
            email='bsahenov@mail.ru')
        self.user1.set_password('123456')
        self.user1.is_active = True
        self.user1.save()
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username=self.user1.username, password=self.user1.password)